# Angular2 multiple constructor implementations are not allowed TS2392

Tags: angular

How can I get around using multiple constructors within a component? Currently I am getting the error:

> 'Multiple constructor implementations are not allowed'.

```
questions: any[];
constructor( service: QuestionSignupStepOneService ) { 
    this.questions = service.getQuestions(); 
}
constructor( service: QuestionSignupStepOneAService ) { 
    this.questions = service.getQuestions(); 
}
```

Is there anyway to simplify what I am trying to do? The code compiles properly but will only run through the first service, ignoring the second.

Edit in 2021: I realized long ago that this was a silly question, but I'm leaving this up because if I did not understand constructors enough so to ask the question then other might find themselves here as well

Comment: Can't you just use a comma: `constructor( service: QuestSignupStepOneService, serviceA:QuestionSignupStepOneAService)` ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?polymorphism?

Comment: @Kilmazing I don't think so. Getting this error now:  error TS2304: Cannot find name 'QuestSignupStepOneService'.

`questions: any[];
 constructor( service: QuestSignupStepOneService, serviceA: QuestionSignupStepOneAService ) { 
  this.questions = service.getQuestions(); 
  this.questions = serviceA.getQuestions(); 
 }`

Comment: @anthonyc it appears I am...perhaps I'm over complicating things

Comment: @EricBerndt, should it be `QuestionSignupStepOneService` instead of `QuestSignupStepOneService`?

I guess it's should be done in the app.js file where you register the service, such as `if(yourUseCase){module.service('QuestionSignupStepOneService ', QuestionSignupStepOneService );}else{module.service('QuestionSignupStepOneService ', QuestionSignupStepOneAService  )`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Making multiple constructors with the same parameters doesn't make sense unless they have different types, in Typescript you can do the following:

```ts
class Foo {

  questions: any[];

  constructor(service: QuestionSignupStepOneService, param2?: Param2Type) { 

    this.questions = service.getQuestions();

    if(param2){
      console.log(param2);
    }
  }
}
```

This is equal to two constructors, the first one is  `new Foo(service)` and the second one is `new Foo(service, param2)`.

Use `?` to state that the parameter is optional.

If you want two constructors with the same parameter but for different types you can use this:

```ts
class Foo {

  questions: any[];

  constructor(service: QuestionSignupStepOneService | QuestionSignupStepOneAService) {

    if(service instanceof QuestionSignupStepOneService){
       this.questions = service.getQuestions(); 
    }
    else {
       this.questions = service.getDifferentQuestions(); 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this (it's grammatically correct, but don't know yet if it will work):

```
  constructor(private _myService: MyService, private _myOtherService: MyOtherService) {
    super(_myService);
    this.dataSource = new MyThingDataSource(this._myOtherService);
    }
```