# How to use two constructors in Angular

Tags: angular, forms, request, httpclient, angular-forms

I have used one constructor to create my form:

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
```

and now I need another constructor to send its data:

```
constructor(private http : HttpClient) {}
```

all in the same component. How can I do this? Help me please!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 multiple constructor implementations are not allowed TS2392](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028242/angular2-multiple-constructor-implementations-are-not-allowed-ts2392)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inject all the services you need in the constructor:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

/**
 * Component
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your.component.css']
})
export class YourComponent {
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private http : HttpClient) {}
}
```